# PHP - FILTER_VALIDATE_URL not finding subdomains with underscore

Tags: php

Why the PHP function: FILTER_VALIDATE_URL thinks that an URL with a subdomain that contains an underscore is invalid?

```
<?php
$url = "http://smiling_politely.blogspot.com";

if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
    echo("$url is a valid URL");
} else {
    echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
?>
```

How can I make sure that this FILTER_VALIDATE_URL includes such existing URLs (possibly the fastest way for execution)?

Comment: Still open https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64948

Comment: Hmm - 2013-05-30 14:59 UTC, now it's over 3 years..

Comment: Nobody has decided if it should be changed or not I guess.

Comment: Maybe there's a temporary fix to accept such subdomains..

Comment: Make your own validation function (or find one on the internet)

Comment: @Tom you should probably try `parse_url` to see if it parses anything. It tends to work better

Comment: ok that may be possible (even though I'd hope this in-built function would be faster). Plus I see from manual about parse_url: "This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts."

Comment: Could `str_replace` `_` with space or `-`.  But then you could get a `http-://` or `.com-` or something.

Comment: Underscores aren't allowed in hostnames. Server names in URLs are hostnames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I came up with this solution, hopefully it's going to work well..

```
<?php

$url = "http://smiling_politely.blogspot.com";
$check = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_HOST);

if(null!==$check) echo 'Valid'; else echo 'NOT valid.';

?>
```

Comment: `parse_url` is also better because it uses [RFC3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html) which is what is currently in effect. In contrast `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` uses [RFC2396](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html) which is obsolete.